# Silverstripe 4.6 setup .env - vars, missing install.php, language?

Tags: installation, environment-variables, silverstripe

In the docs, they say, the install.php no longer exists within SS 4.6.x.
So you have to setup with .env - variables

my .env looks like this:

```
SS_BASE_URL="http://localhost/SS_4_6_1"
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLPDODatabase"
SS_DATABASE_NAME="ss_4_6_1"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD="root"
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="localhost"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="root"
SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="XXX"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="XXX"
```

Doing a .../dev/build...
Database is created.

I know i can change Cms-language to German for the Default- admin in the CMS.

BUT all pages created while setup are in English. (inclusive Error - Pages) ??

CAN YOU CHANGE THE DEFAULT - LANGUAGE TO e.g. GERMAN FOR SETTING UP THE SITE?

EDIT: It would be nice, to set language in .env:

```
SS_DEFAULT_LOCALE="de_DE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can change the default language for setting up the site.

Before we run the initial `dev/build` we can add the following to our app config.yml:

```
SilverStripe\i18n\i18n:
  default_locale: 'de'
```

When `dev/build` runs it will populate the default pages with the specified language.